# Ошибка при создании подписи REST API OKX python

Tags: python, api, http, https

Всем здравствуйте, пытаюсь продать крипту используя REST API от биржи OKX. Полностью следовал документации, но при запуске кода получаю ошибку: `{"msg":"Invalid Sign","code":"50113"}`

Вот код:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
from config import APIs
import base64


api_public = APIs['OKX']['public']
api_private = APIs['OKX']['private']
passphrase = APIs['OKX']['passphrase']


def make_signature(timestamp, body):
    string = timestamp + 'POST' + '/api/v5/trade/order' + json.dumps(body)
    signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), string.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest())
    return signature


def create_order(symbol, side, size: str):
    timestamp = str(datetime.now().utcnow().isoformat()[:-3]+'Z')

    body = {
        'instId': symbol,
        'tdMode': 'cash',
        'side': side,
        'ordType': 'market',
        'sz': size
    }
    headers = {
        'OK-ACCESS-KEY': api_public,
        'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': make_signature(timestamp, body),
        'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post('https://www.okx.com/api/v5/trade/order', headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_order('FLOW-USDT', 'sell', '1.96')
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно решение оказалось простым: я передавал в функцию `make_signature` словарь body и уже в ней делал `json.dumps()`, а теперь я сначала делаю `json.dumps()` а уже потом передаю body в `make_signature`

Вот рабочий код:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
from datetime import datetime

import requests

from config import APIs

api_public = APIs['OKX']['public']
api_private = APIs['OKX']['private']
passphrase = APIs['OKX']['passphrase']
base_url = 'https://www.okx.com'


def make_signature(timestamp, body):
    message = timestamp + 'POST' + '/api/v5/trade/order' + body
    signature = base64.b64encode(
        hmac.new(api_private.encode('utf-8'), message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    )
    return signature


def create_order(symbol, side, size):
    timestamp = str(datetime.now().utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z')

    body = json.dumps({
        'instId': symbol,
        'tdMode': 'cash',
        'side': side,
        'ordType': 'market',
        'sz': size
    })
    headers = {
        'OK-ACCESS-KEY': api_public,
        'OK-ACCESS-SIGN': make_signature(timestamp, str(body)),
        'OK-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
        'OK-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    response = requests.post('https://www.okx.com/api/v5/trade/order', headers=headers, data=body)
    print(response.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_order('USDT-USDC', 'buy', '2.0746')
```